# Downloading a publicly-shared file from OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

When I create a share link in the UI with the "Anyone with this link can view this item" option, I get a URL that looks like `https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=XXX!YYYY&authkey=!ZZZZZ&ithint=<contentType>`.  What I can't figure out is how to use this URL from code to download the content of the file.  Hitting the link gives HTML for a page to show the file.

How can I construct a call to download the file?  Also, is there a way to construct a call to get some (XML/JSON) metadata about the file, and maybe even a preview or something?  I want to be able to do this all without prompting a user for credentials, and all the API docs are about how to make *authenticated* calls.  I want to make anonymous calls to get publicly-shared files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a read over https://dev.onedrive.com - it documents how you can make a query to our service to get the metadata for an item, along with URLs that can be used to directly download the content.

**Update with more details**

Sorry, the documentation you need for your specific scenario is still in process (along with the associated SDK changes) so I'll give you an overview of how to do it.

There's a sibling to the `/drives` path called `/shares` which accepts a sharing URL (such as the one you have above) in an encoded format and allows you to get metadata for the item it represents. This does *not* require authentication provided the sharing URL has a valid `authkey`.

The encoding scheme for the id is `u!<UrlSafeBase64EncodedUrl>`, where `<UrlSafeBase64EncodedUrl>` follows the guidelines outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) (trim the `=` characters from the end).

Here's a snippet that should give you an idea of the whole process:

```
string originalUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=XXX!YYYY&authkey=!foo";
byte[] urlAsUtf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalUrl);
string utf8BytesAsBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(urlAsUtf8Bytes);
string encodedUrl = "u!" + utf8BytesAsBase64String.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');

string metadataUrl = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/" + encodedUrl + "/root";
```

From there you can append `/content` if you want to get the contents of the file, or you can start navigating through if the URL represents a folder (e.g. `/children/childfile.txt`)

Comment: Those APIs all say they require authentication - I have a link to a publicly-shared file and want to get file metadata and download it without authenticating.

Or is this a case of the APIs not providing a complete coverage of what you can do from the UI?

Comment: Updated the answer with actual instructions as our documentation is not yet updated to include it.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Brad! I have some questions: 1. Am I right that "authkey" value never expires (unless sharing is cancelled)? 2. I use JS SDK and get link https://1drv.ms/u/s!AAAA_BBBB. If I open the link, I am redirected to https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21CCCC&cid=DDDD&id=DDDD%21EEE&parId=root&o=OneUp. Then I can create a link https://onedrive.live.com/download?authkey=%21CCCC&resid=DDDD%21EEE. Is it a reliable way to download shared files (unless sharing is cancelled)? 3. Is there a way to translate "s!AAAA_BBBB" into "%21CCCC" & "DDDD%21EEE" without requesting OneDrive server?

Comment: Response in comment = terse :). The auth key never expires since it is revocable. The better way to get the download url is to do what our outlined in this answer - create the api url as outlined, and then add /content on the end