# Getting download links from OneDrive filenames without sign-in with user/password

Tags: c++, c, rest, onedrive

I have an application in C/C++ which displays items images (JPG) stored on my OneDrive.
I use https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/addressing.htm to get a download link from each image filename stored on OneDrive.

This works but the problem is that I have to authenticate like described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659750.aspx
and this authentication needs my user/password (just before getting the authorization code)

I have automated user/password in my requests in C/C++ but this is bad because anyone can extract them with tools like Wireshark.

So, Is there a way to get a download link from a OneDrive filename (not id that I don't know) with REST apis without authenticating with user/password ?

(if I trace the shared link (on the parent directory of JPGs), I see it uses https://skyapi.onedrive.live.com/API/2/GetItems?... with a generic AppId=1141147648 and various parameters) but I cannot extract
all the items (dozens of thousands) with this command just to find 1 particular item on each request to get the download link because it would take ages)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The https protocol crypts away the credentials you pass.

Comment: *I have automated user/password in my requests in C/C++ but this is bad because anyone can extract them with tools like Wireshark.* - The password is never actually sent. It's part of a challenge/response process over https, which is an enrypted channel.  Just do everything over https and you'll be fine.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at creating a *sharing link*.  That might be what you are after: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/sharing_createLink.htm

Comment: Ok, so I should not worry about passing my user/password in HTTPS requests (and as I said, I already use a sharing link (the parent folder of all my items) to get individual items download urls with REST apis)

Comment: If you really want to do this without authentication, I would see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015295/downloading-a-publicly-shared-file-from-onedrive.

This should allow you to download from a publicly shared folder without authenticating.

Comment: It cannot work because my sharing url is the parent folder and I cannot download a file from its name, apart listing all files id like with GetItems, which is a lot too long...