# How can I set public folder permissions in OneDrive?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have been using this API to list and read files from my *Public* folder in *OneDrive personal* cloud service:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{item-id}/children
```

I could simply access folder's content in C# without authentication:

```
using (var http = new HttpClient()) {
    var json = http.GetStringAsync($"https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{itemId}/children").Result;
    var data = JObject.Parse(json);
    ...
}
```

This API suddenly stopped working. It returns 404 status code with this content:

```
{"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"Item does not exist"}}
```

But the API is still working for other public folders owned by other accounts. For example this URL still works:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/AB8DAAB49807BE4%21140/children
```

How can I set folder's permission to *public*? Why the API stopped working?

Comment: The work-around can be found below the question [Downloading a publicly-shared file from OneDrive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015295/downloading-a-publicly-shared-file-from-onedrive).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is in a process of removing the public sharing feature. It's been a source of confusing for end users who don't understand the difference between sharing something as *public* and sharing a view or edit link to a file.

[source](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/86)